# what free app can i use to resize an image to specific heigh x width?

Tags: image-editing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows tool to resize / crop images before uploading to web site](https://superuser.com/questions/165810/windows-tool-to-resize-crop-images-before-uploading-to-web-site)

I have an image that is huge and i want to re-size it down to 375 x 210 px to enter a competition.

I would like to keep the aspect ratio of the image the same and not have to crop if I dont have to. i dont think my original image is the same ratio or proportions so i understand ill need to crop to get that in line but the rest should just be shrunk. that is to say i dont want to have to crop a small part of the image to meet the 375 x 210 px requirement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Irfanview](http://www.irfanview.com/) is a very simple and free software tool to get this done quickly. Weighing in at 1.4MB, it's a fast download too.

Answer (score 2):

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) is a powerful, but complicated free image manipulation program that can resize and crop images.

In the menu "Image" is an option "Scale Image" that you can use to scale the image. You can use the option "Crop to selection" from the "Image" menu to crop the image, if necessary.

Answer (score 2):

I use the Windows Power Toy "Image Resizer".  Just right-click on an image an choose "Resize Pictures". You can resize single or multiple pictures with one click.

For Windows XP, you can download here http://www.microsoft.com/windowsxp/downloads/powertoys/xppowertoys.mspx

For Windows 7 and Vista, you can go here to download:
http://imageresizer.codeplex.com/